# How many airlocks does the ISS have?

Tags: iss, pirs, airlock, quest-joint-airlock, poisk

In this context, I mean, a way to get out of the station, without depressurizing the entire station.

The obvious ones are:

- Quest airlock on Unity (Node 1).
- Pirs (DC-1) airlock

Does Poisk (DC-2?  Or is MRM 1?) have an airlock?

When Nauka launches, the small airlock attached to Rassvet will be moved over.

Kibo (JAXA model) has a small airlock for experiments.

Can either of the 2 PMA's be depressurized and compartmentalized, so that they could be used as an airlock?

CBM ports cannot.

Can any other Russian segment components provide airlock style services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you count the Transfrer Compartment of Zvezda

[image: Transfrer Compartment of Zvezda]

and Pressurized Adaptor of Zarya (each looking like a spherical part of the module)? 
There even was [an official EVA from TC of Zvezda.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_spacewalks)

MLM Nauka is going to have a a similar spherical compartment. In addition to that a separate airlock for experiments will be provided. See [this short 2012 Roscosmos video about MLM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-M7gCWzJSx4#t=4m00). At 4:00 the airlock is demonstrated. 
Sorry this is all in russian.

Comment: I would have, except they are now enclosed, by being docked to each other? Or is TC of Zvezda, the aft port? In which casem sure.

Comment: Well, yes. They'd need to undock all the pendant modules. Think about the ISS not as a celestial palace with fixed configuration, but a swarm of modules moving around each other, undocking and re-docking with each other as needed.